# How can I disable links and formatting in Adium?

Tags: settings, copy-paste, adium, irc

Adium attempts to support rich text formatting (italic, bold, underline) and links. For instance, if I paste some text from my browser, Adium might display the message I'm sending as:

[image: message with italic, bold, and link text]

which gets received as:

[image: message with unformatted text and raw URL]

I never want this feature, because the message Adium tells me I've sent is different from the message I'm actually sending; I can't tell what I've sent unless I send a copy to myself or spy on the wire.

My current workaround is to paste as plain text (⇧⌘V or ⇧⌥⌘V) and avoid using the in-Adium formatting tools.

How can I disable this feature?